# Can't count an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've encountered a very odd issue in a class I'm creating. Here is a snippet of the class below and it's output:

```
class WeirdHappenings
{
    protected $filters_list = array();

...

    function build()
    {
        $filters_count = count($this->filters_list);

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->filters_list);
        echo "<br>" . $filters_count . " is the count";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Before you ask, yes filters_list is a populated array which is populated during the execution of the class. The Vardump proves that:

```
array(2) {
  ["filter_1"]=>
  string(17) "calendar year nbr"
  ["filter_2"]=>
  string(18) "reviewer type desc"
}

0 is the count
```

How can this be possible? It's an array with two elements yet count can't tell me how big it is?

```
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May 13 2010 20:03:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

`error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

This is the resolution:

```
class WeirdHappenings
{
    protected $filters_list = array();
    protected $thing = array("foo" => "bar", "ack" => "bar");

    function WeirdHappenings()
    {

    }

    function makeMeCry()
    {
        $filters = array();
        $filter_count = 1;

        $crapola = array("f1" => array("name" => "calendar year nbr"), "f2" => array("name" => "reviewer type desc"));

        foreach( $crapola as $key => $data )
        {
            $filters["filter_$filter_count"] = $data['name'];
            $filter_count++;
        }

        $this->filters_list = $filters;
    }

    function build()
    {       
        $filters_count = count($this->filters_list);
        $this->makeMeCry();
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->filters_list);
        var_dump($this->thing);
        echo "<br>" . $filters_count . " is the count of the filters";
        echo "<br>" . count($this->thing) . " is the count of the thing";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}

$weirdthings = new WeirdHappenings();
$weirdthings->build();
```

As pointed out in numerous comments the count was being performed prior to the population of the array.

Comment: Have you set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`? If not, please do so.

Comment: @nikic Error reporting has been set to E_ALL | E_STRICT and still no errors reported.

Comment: Instead of using ... (and thus hiding the probable culprit) try to provide a minimal reproducing code sample. Usually in the process of generating such a sample the error will get revealed.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic That's not the case. All that needs to be known is there in the code. the var dump of the array shows that it is set. However a count can't be made of it.

Comment: I will however create a simple class to demonstrate this issue.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi: We can't paste your code and run it to reproduce the behavior. As long as we can't reproduce it, we can't know what's wrong. There has to be something else

Comment: Most likely you have an error somewhere else.

The code above will say the count is 2 for sure.

Comment: I second needing more code. I can't imagine how the snippets you provided could produce that output.

Comment: @Mike It doesn't.  I just threw a simple test case together and it works just fine.  He's probably getting the count before actually populating the array.

Comment: Reproducing the code is difficult as it requires a db. The snippet shows that I'm dumping an array, then trying to count that array - the code in build function is un-altered in that respect.

Comment: You don't require a DB for a count() to fail... unless it has something to do with the problem. **Minimal** reproducing code sample is what usually helps. Minimal being the operative word. That helps you isolating the problem and finding something you didn't even consider had something to do with the error.

Comment: This was resolved. I created a test class and noticed the issue.

Comment: Now that's an easy resolution. I already thought that something returns an object of a class which implements ArrayAccess but doesn't implement Countable or something like this.

Comment: @Aircule you can see the issue in the small example "WeirdHappenings" I essentially was counting the empty array, invoking the function in the class which populated that array, then spouting off silliness as the count was correct.

My main problem is that I was calling the function that populated the array from a test script, when i removed that line the weirdness began. The WeirdHappenings class and helpful comments from everyone helped to pinpoint this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a programming error on my part. Where I was counting an array prior to populating it.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($this->filters_list);
echo "<br>" . count($this->filters_list) . " is the count";
echo "</pre>";
```

i'm sure this would return 2. if not there is probably some "php magic" going on with __get(), __set(), __sleep() or something like that

Comment: __get and __set wouldn't be called from inside a class, since the variable exists and is accessible. __sleep() is completely unrelated.

Comment: It does not return two. __get and __set are not being used within the Class. Quite literally there is an array and it's not being counted.

Answer (score 1):

PHP count() returns zero only in two cases:

```
echo count(null); // returns 0
echo count(array()); // returns 0
```

So, 
1) Check your spelling; 2) Turn on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

3) Try to run your code on another version of PHP (without Suhosin-Patch).